# Visual Studio search results highlighting

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to highlight search results in Visual Studio? Note, I'm specifically asking about the "Find Results" window. An example of what I'm looking for is the GNU grep --color option.

Comment: The new Visual Assist X version highlight serach result in the code window, but it does not work in the search results.

Answer (score 3):

This feature isn't available in VS, all what you can do is to use "Bookmark all" button in the Find dialog (expand "Find options" to see the button).

Or you can use a plugin to do that, such as [ReSharper Highlight Usages in File feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/UsageSearch/highlightUsagesInFile.html).

Answer (score 1):

The new coderush express does highlighting on a term if you tab over it. So if you want to tab through all instances of p_fooOBJECT, put the cursor in p_fooOBJECT and hit tab and they will all be underlined (or eles I completely misundersttod your question.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a free [Find Results Highlighter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/18fc5767-d3e6-4483-adbd-7396b0ea164e) plugin for Visual Studio 2010.